Announcing the August–September 2024 topic challenge: August Wilson
In accordance with our meta agreement to have topic challenges
and a later meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month,
it is time to announce the August–September 2024 topic challenge.
Based on the number of votes (+5, -1), our next topic challenge will be
the works of August Wilson

What's a topic challenge?
See the meta posts linked above, and also this main Meta post.
In short, during August and September 2024 you are invited to try to get hold of one or more of the works by August Wilson, read them, and ask or answer questions about them.
Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during August and September too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.
How can I take part?
By getting hold of one or more of the works by August Wilson and

asking good questions about it or
answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge or
submitting a book review to our Tumblr blog.

Questions about these works should be tagged august-wilson (and a tag for any book-length work).
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.
Below is EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine's
presentation:

Theater (other than Shakespeare) is somewhat underrepresented on our site, and August Wilson's works are particularly relevant now in light of recent events. August Wilson (1945 – 2005) received two Pulitzer Prizes for Drama and a number of other awards.

What's next?

Vote for the next topic challenge or propose your own!


Very fitting that this should start in August :-)

List of all questions posted in this topic challenge

Which game is "that 651"? by EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine, 24/08/2024 (HNQ, 7 votes, 1 answer)
Why did Boy Willie refer to toast as "grilled bread"? by EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine, 02/09/2024 (2 votes, no answer)
Interpretation of the character Gabe in Fences? by Rand al'Thor, 26/09/2024 (4 votes, no answer)
Why did it take so long for Jitney to appear on Broadway? by Rand al'Thor, 27/09/2024 (HNQ, 5 votes, 1 answer)
"and the gates of heaven stand open as wide as God's closet" in August Wilson's Fences by Tsundoku, 28/09/2024 (1 vote, no answer)


The highest-voted and most viewed of these is Which game is "that 651"? by EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine, with a score of 7 and approximately 1000 views by the end of September.
2 questions received at least one answer. Two answers were submitted in total.
